# TableViewController not showing json data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm a beginner and I've read everything on StackOverflow about my problem - my app with json data doesn't show anything on TableViewController. I'm probably missing something obvious, but the help is appreciated very very much. (I'm using the latest Xcode 5 DP, if it's important).

`TableVC.h`

```
@interface TableVC : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *kinos;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;

-(void)fetchKinos;

@end
```

And the `TableVC.m` file is

```
@interface TableVC ()

@end

@implementation TableVC


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self fetchKinos];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)fetchKinos {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.adworldmagazine.com/json.json"]];
        NSError *error;
        _kinos = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _kinos.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"KinoCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSArray *entities = [_kinos objectForKey:@"entities"];
    NSDictionary *kino = [entities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *title = [kino objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *original = [title objectForKey:@"original"];
    NSString *ru = [title objectForKey:@"ru"];
    cell.textLabel.text = original;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = ru;

    return cell;

}
@end
```

Comment: You're sure that your kinos holds your json data? By which I mean the problem is with the TableView and not the json?

Comment: S. Check your response data first.

Comment: yeah i'm sure it worked with master-detail application

Comment: Are you set delegate and dataSource for you tableView?

Comment: set breakpoints and check where the problem is then if you can't solve, then ask. No one can help you this way.

Comment: the storyboard is doing it for me automatically

Comment: You have not provided enough information. `1)` Make sure you use `self.kinos` everywhere  `2)` Make sure that the `kinos` dictionary is actually populated `3)` Make sure you have implemented all the required tableview protocols (`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`) `4)` Come back and let us know where the problem is and we may be able to assist

Comment: Check your table view outlet and delegate connection. Change the row account as amar mentioned below. Your code working fine After this changes In my side.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response dictionary contains an array of `entities` whose count needs to be returned from the table view method.

[image]

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.kinos objectForKey:@"entities"] count];
}
```

Also, a suggestion, when you declare `strong` properties, try to access them as `self.propertyName` instead of accessing the ivar like `_propertyName`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

I accessed your url- http://www.adworldmagazine.com/json.json on my browser.
The response returns a JSON with root: dictionary.

So,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _kinos.count;
}
```

wont work.

Use this instead:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [_kinos objectForKey:@"entities"].count;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: I edited my answer, to include a way to sort out the issue as well.

Comment: Now you're just re-stating the answer given by @amar above.